# How do you unescape '\' in JSX template literal?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

```
<pre>{`
   I want to be formatted with
 \
   in the text
`}</pre>
```

How do I get '\' to appear in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add another backslash `\\`